# Android layout size best practise

Tags: android, android-layout, height, android-linearlayout

I have a case where i have multiple linear layouts vertically one after another (max 5). Now each linear layout has multiple text views some of which are visible and some remain GONE based on whether i have got a value for it from server or not, hence textview visibility remains random for each linear layout. 
Because linear layout has height as wrap content (as i want to adjust everything that remains visible at runtime) heights vary for each linear layout but i want that to be uniform for all.
Another issue if instead of wrap content i take height as 100dp would that be a good practise? If yes how will i support different screen sizes in case i use this hard coded value.

To summarize how do we best handle sizes at production level (even in listviews) where sizes may vary from view by view depending on content do we use fix heights? min heights ? max heights ? wrap content so that every view seems uniform.

Answer (score 0):

You can use weight attribute instead of fixing height. Set height to 0dp and a similar value for weight attrib to all views you want to have same size.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with views adjusting height as per available content. Even sometimes it's more pleasant of an experience if designed properly. Specially in your example. Visualize a list of tweets Google now cards, or notification drawer for that matter.

Having said that sometimes it is required to keep views  to some minimum height. In such cases `minHeight` param can be used.

Example:

[image]